# Python, spyder execution very low when using numpy.fft.ifft

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# load sampling frequency and cut.
ori_wav_fs,ori_wav_data=wavfile.read('thing1.wav')
ori_wav_data=ori_wav_data[:,1]

# Using Fast Fourier Transform and plot with proper axis.
ori_fd_y=np.fft.fft(ori_wav_data)

# cut the fundmental frequency
ff=ori_fd_y[0]
har_fd_y=np.delete(ori_fd_y,0)
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(abs(har_fd_y)[:50]) 

# Using Inverse Fourier Transform back to time domain for these harmonics frequency
har_td=np.fft.ifft(har_fd_y)
har_td=np.real(har_td)
#plt.figure(4)
#plt.plot(har_td)
```

as the above code, when i run the file, i need wait for more than 10mins to see the plot and outcome in the IPython console in Spyder. I tested i can run numpy.fft.ifft with the orignal data with few seconds , while here i deleted a element in the array why it needs more than 10 mins ? is there anyway i can fix it ?